# UDT are not available on protocols less than 3, please update config"

Tags: gocql

Using UDT:

Note: cqlsh: `show version`

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.1 | CQL spec 3.3.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

Tables

```
CREATE TYPE fullname (
  firstname text,
  lastname text
);

CREATE TABLE sample (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name frozen <fullname>
);
```

Code:

```
type Frozen struct {
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string `json:"lastname"`
}

myobj := &Frozen{
    Firstname: "pony",
    Lastname:  "jim",
}

if err := session.Query(`INSERT INTO sample (id, name) VALUES (?,?)`,
    2, myobj).Exec(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I get:

```
UDT are not available on protocols less than 3, please update config
```

Update config?

Answer (score 0):

I updated Cassandra to 3.3 and it worked.

The error message tricked me into thinking that having "Native protocol v4" was ok running on Cassandra 2.2.

Upgrading to 3.3 I also had to add the following, just after defining keyspace when creating a session:
ClusterName.ProtoVersion = 4